# File upload multi-select

Tags: c#, jquery, file-upload, web, multi-select

I'm not positive if this is even possible, but is there any way to enable a user to ctrl+click (ie, multi-select) files on a website?

Screen shot of what I would like to be able to do via an upload tool, taken from just my standard file explorer:

[image: Multi-select]

In case this is relevant, the back-end of the site is in C# and the front-end scripting is JS/jQuery.

Comment: Do you mean 'multi-select in a popup window that appears when they click Browse.. to select files for upload?'

Comment: There's no multi-file control in plain HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML4/XHTML1's file upload element only allows for single file uploads.  You can use Flash or a plugin to get the behavior you want.  You could use JQuery to create a dynamic form that would allow multiple uploads but they'd still need to be selected individually.

If you're OK with only supporting HTML5-capable browsers, you can `<input type="file" multiple="multiple>` and get this behavior.

Comment: yes! this is great... now, do you know how i handle those files for upload, or anything like that?

Comment: Can't say I do.  I've been out of web development for a year or two, I just remember being excited when I saw it work with Chrome inside of Gmail the first time.

Comment: i've figured out how to work with it on the back end (`Request.Files` has all the files) but I'd like a way to intercept it on the client side so I can react accordingly, mainly to the number being uploaded.

Comment: @Jason Hi Jason. I have an example that uses Plupload see https://github.com/tommiller85/Image-Bank-MVC